# Multiple accounts same-session-login

Tags: javascript, twitter, meteor, instagram

I am building a meteor app. I am rather new to this framework. 
I want the user to login with both instagram and twitter `at the same time`.

So, guy enter site -> popup appears obliging him to login to both twitter and instagram -> guy logs in with both -> do stuff.

I need this so that I can get access_tokens to do mega api calls on the above mentioned services.

Can it be done? Or there's only one user+service per session?

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing these services with access tokens through REST calls, so yes, it can be simply done. The sessions are managed by Instagram and Twitter, and they do not interact with each other.